# mySQL queries being messed up

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, rows

im doing a query in php as such

```
 $grabdme = "SELECT * from comment_votes where username = '".$_SESSION['username']."' and vote = 'dislike' and comment_id = ".$comments['id'];
 $rungrabdme = mysqli_query($link, $grabdislikes);
 $ifidislike = mysqli_num_rows($rungrabdme);
```

Basically its this in simple words

> SELECT * from comment_votes where username = 'marshall' and vote = 'dislike' and comment_id = 4

phpmyadmin returns 0 results, but when run from my script it returns 2 rows which are

> id - 6, comment_id - 4, vote - dislike, username - LUcase
>  id - 7,
>   comment_id - 4, vote - dislike, username - nicknick

i am expecting 0 results, but why is php returning 2 results?

Comment: It is just impossible. Most likely you see the results of *another* query

Comment: So if you do `echo "query: $grabdme, results: $ifidislike";` you see the above query and `2`?

Comment: Maybe this is because `$rungrabdme` contains the result of the query `$grabdislikes`... seems like you mixed up a few variables. As an aside: this approach is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: yeah i see the above query and 2

Comment: oh how dumb am i, i forget to notice $rungrabdme :|

Comment: can you tell me how this approach is vulnerable to sql injection?
ive sanitized the variables before doing the query :>

Answer (score 1):

Are'nt you executing `$grabdislikes` query instead of `$grabme` ?